# Sort Array According to Giving input In Js

Tags: javascript, sorting, jsx, swap, arrayobject

I have the array like :

`Arr = [{name:"abc",age:1},{name:"a",age:4},{name:"ac",age:3},{name:"abc",age:2},{name:"abc",age:9}]`

I want to change it like this:

`[{name:"abc",age:1},{name:"abc",age:2},{name:"abc",age:9},{name:"a",age:4},{name:"ac",age:3}]`

by sorting or swapping it.

Comment: what is the wanted sort order?

Comment: obj with the same name come first or user input  name should listed first

Comment: Use triple backticks around your code to format it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
arr1.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.name.startsWith(b.name)) { return -1; }
    if(a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
    if(a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
```

Comment: that result is different from the order in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect same named objects with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the flatted values back.

This approach keeps the given order for `name` and groups this object with same name together.

```js
var array = [{ name: "abc", age: 1 }, { name: "a", age: 4 }, { name: "ac", age: 3 }, { name: "abc", age: 2 }, { name: "abc", age: 9 }];

array = Array
    .from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.name, [...(m.get(o.name) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    )
    .flat();

console.log(array);
```